# Error while building a Docker Image. "Exception: Cython-generated file 'pandas/_libs/algos.c' not found."

Tags: python, pandas, docker, pip, containers

I used to be able to build docker images based on the following

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7 

COPY ./* ./app/
WORKDIR /app/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["python", "application.py"]
```

requirements.txt

```
Flask==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
Flask-Cors==3.0.8
pandas==0.25.0
```

But  for  some  reason now get the following error:

```
Exception: Cython-generated file 'pandas/_libs/algos.c' not found.

Cython is required to compile pandas from a development branch.

Please Cython or download a release package of pandas.
```

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sj5w0hrl/pandas_95358ad691f84ba592a47a0ee2865610/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sj5w0hrl/pandas_95358ad691f84ba592a47a0ee2865610/setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-gq03hxk9/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /usr/local/include/python3.7m/pandas Check the logs for full command output.
#8 29.80 WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
#8 29.80 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Also observed

`Building wheel for pandas (setup.py): started` earlier in the process.

I am able to run the application.py in an anaconda python 3.7 env, with the exact same library versions and am not sure why the Docker image can't be built.

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Comment: those deps are all super old -- try using more modern versions

Answer (score 0):

looks like nothing went wrong when running your code snippet

```
❯ docker build --progress=plain .
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 sha256:4e71406ebab08442ac664cde223b092f6776344e6fb4ddfdff4dfbb838bcfe9e
#1 transferring dockerfile: 172B done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 sha256:1a10e5d0ab49608585f614ecfaa0bfe97ccc2d31060e198df8a1980e44458991
#2 transferring context: 2B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7
#3 sha256:2e83735093f2e645c7660e349795ae80186113afc054af8bdc7501e99da12131
#3 DONE 0.2s

#5 [internal] load build context
#5 sha256:8f0c2f0a3180ca58eaa2b66c92cb89696bbb21d93d9d0ff7c39d98d55b355606
#5 transferring context: 624B done
#5 DONE 0.0s

#4 [1/4] FROM docker.io/library/python:3.7@sha256:c185410ab69dcdfb5e5edabf0d78bc5655a210a4e263001b4bc4bc1d9e6f6309
#4 sha256:fd9bad7021e0dc27c7bb2b55e29fecf8c8a6ad84d1c7159ed9eaa62a493ba344
#4 CACHED

#6 [2/4] COPY ./* ./app/
#6 sha256:d40647c650fc7755d12ce659cd5a785a62d11f98b65cdde20f0bd9d6686bd152
#6 DONE 0.0s

#7 [3/4] WORKDIR /app/
#7 sha256:6ea14a12742c3186cb146b56b90cef310260d2bd5ac17ced3c64f2a2f8716543
#7 DONE 0.0s

#8 [4/4] RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
#8 sha256:0f52dc2b38d612e5f77fa250cd659dbb1193e621e6e17858778f965f0bc9f3e2
#8 1.260 Collecting Flask==1.1.1
#8 1.303   Downloading Flask-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
#8 1.381 Collecting Werkzeug==1.0.1
#8 1.394   Downloading Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
#8 1.489 Collecting Flask-Cors==3.0.8
#8 1.498   Downloading Flask_Cors-3.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
#8 1.784 Collecting pandas==0.25.0
#8 1.806   Downloading pandas-0.25.0-cp37-cp37m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.4 MB)
#8 4.294 Collecting itsdangerous>=0.24
#8 4.317   Downloading itsdangerous-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
#8 4.403 Collecting Jinja2>=2.10.1
#8 4.428   Downloading Jinja2-3.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
#8 4.568 Collecting click>=5.1
#8 4.585   Downloading click-8.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
#8 4.675 Collecting Six
#8 4.695   Downloading six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
#8 4.922 Collecting pytz>=2017.2
#8 4.941   Downloading pytz-2021.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
#8 5.577 Collecting numpy>=1.13.3
#8 5.590   Downloading numpy-1.21.4-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (15.7 MB)
#8 9.649 Collecting python-dateutil>=2.6.1
#8 9.658   Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
#8 9.847 Collecting importlib-metadata
#8 9.853   Downloading importlib_metadata-4.8.2-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
#8 9.971 Collecting MarkupSafe>=2.0
#8 9.982   Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp37-cp37m-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (31 kB)
#8 10.10 Collecting zipp>=0.5
#8 10.11   Downloading zipp-3.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 kB)
#8 10.15 Collecting typing-extensions>=3.6.4
#8 10.16   Downloading typing_extensions-3.10.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
#8 10.29 Installing collected packages: zipp, typing-extensions, MarkupSafe, importlib-metadata, Werkzeug, Six, Jinja2, itsdangerous, click, pytz, python-dateutil, numpy, Flask, pandas, Flask-Cors
#8 14.42 Successfully installed Flask-1.1.1 Flask-Cors-3.0.8 Jinja2-3.0.2 MarkupSafe-2.0.1 Six-1.16.0 Werkzeug-1.0.1 click-8.0.3 importlib-metadata-4.8.2 itsdangerous-2.0.1 numpy-1.21.4 pandas-0.25.0 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2021.3 typing-extensions-3.10.0.2 zipp-3.6.0
#8 14.42 WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
#8 14.55 WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
#8 14.55 You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
#8 DONE 14.7s

#9 exporting to image
#9 sha256:e8c613e07b0b7ff33893b694f7759a10d42e180f2b4dc349fb57dc6b71dcab00
#9 exporting layers
#9 exporting layers 1.0s done
#9 writing image sha256:724cd048bd29bea338521b611527e448b3fc563e3cd0569a9a693bafb2c6018d done
#9 DONE 1.0s

Use 'docker scan' to run Snyk tests against images to find vulnerabilities and learn how to fix them
```